# Creating list< strings> from List<Pair<String,String>>

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8

I have fully list:

```
List<Pair<String,String>> List = new ArrayList<>();
```

I would like to inject first element (String) and create new simple list of it:

```
List<String> localtNameList
```

How can I convert `List<Pair<String,String>>` array to normal `List <String>` using **first** String?

### Answer for Eran

In my model I have:

```
public List<Pair<String,String>> getArtistsWithPhoto ()
{
    List<Pair<String,String>> perfectMapNameAndFoto = new ArrayList<>() ;

    if (ituneResult.getListSongs() != null){
        for (ResultiTune item : ituneResult.getListSongs() ){

            perfectMapNameAndFoto.add(new Pair <String,String> (item.getArtistName(),item.getArtworkUrl100() ));
        }
    }
    if(lastFmResult.getResults().getArtistmatches().getListOfLatsFmArtists() != null) {
        for (ArtistLastFm item : lastFmResult.getResults().getArtistmatches().getListOfLatsFmArtists())
            perfectMapNameAndFoto.add(new Pair<String, String>(item.getName(), item.getUrl()));
    }
    return perfectMapNameAndFoto;

}
```

and in my adapter:
by implementation: 'com.annimon:stream:1.2.1'

```
List<String> localArtistNameList = Stream.of(list).map(Pair::getFirst).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### Solutions by Eric

Android version Pair Class do not have getFirst as Eric mention, so solution was:

```
p -> p.first
```

Final working code:

```
Stream.of(list).map(p -> p.first).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If someone want to use Stream in Android < API 24:

*In Gradle:*

```
implementation 'com.annimon:stream:1.2.1'
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Stream`s:

```
List<String> localtNameList = list.stream().map(Pair::getFirst).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is assuming `Pair` has a `getFirst` method that returns the first element.

Comment: I add answer in your response.

Comment: @htw that's not the right place to add it. If you have more details to add to your question, please edit your question

Comment: ok, I will edit it.

Comment: if I do not have getFirst method?

Comment: @htw do you have some other method in the Pair class that returns the first element of the Pair? It makes sense that a Pair class will have such a method.

Comment: I am using this class : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair

Comment: @htw it's strange this class has no getters for `first` and `second`. You can use `p -> p.first` instead of `Pair::getFirst`.